# How to get passed seconds between actionfilters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have two actions and two action filters like this

```
[filter1]
public actionresult Index()

[filter2]
[httppost]
public actionresult Index(User user)
```

here is filter classes

```
public class filter1:ActionFilterAttribute{
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)}

public class filter2:ActionFilterAttribute{
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)}
```

question is: how can I get passed seconds from filter1 till filter2?

Comment: Use stopwatch. See [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: You do understand that your method(s) could be hit simultaneously by hundreds of users?

Comment: Stephen Muecke   I'm making just Simple Testing app on local machine

Comment: L16H7 I knew Stopwatch class but how can I pass stopwatch object from filter1 to filter2?  i.e.  from one class to another?

Comment: @DatoMaisuradze, You cant. As soon as a request is made to the GT method and the view returned, the controller is disposed. You need to persist the value to a repository and the get it again in the POST method. Alternatively you could add the value to the view and post it back

Comment: I would actually suggest you to use `Glimpse` - http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Execution-Tab. Even though it will not give you the combined timespan, you can still get good analysis on how much time each action, action filter took. Give it a try.

Comment: Your problem is that to communicate between 2 requests you'll have to store _State_ somewhere. You can use all the standard techniques, like Cookies, Server storage, Session object. You can find out about them and pick one. `ActionExecutingContext.RequestContext.Session` might be the easiest, but not recommended for large scale use.

Comment: okay, I'll try all these techniques.  thanks everyone for help